# Why does C++ have two different values for an instance's class attribute?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

In my current C++ project, I have encountered something weird I have never seen before. This is a minimal example to demonstrate the effect. I have two almost empty virtual classes B1, B2.

```
    class B1 {
    public:
        virtual void Func1() = 0;
    }
```

```
    class B2 {
    public:
        virtual void Func2() = 0;
    }
```

... and a class A that inherits from both of them. A has a singleton behavior and is constructed by a static initializer that sets a data attribute of A:

```
class A : public B1, public B2 {
public:
    virtual void Func1() {}

    virtual void Func2() {}

    static A* Initialize(const double dataIn) {
        Instance.data = dataIn;
        return &Instance;
    }

    double data;

protected:
    static A Instance;
}
```

As you can see, B1 and B2 are interchangeable except for the order in which the A-inheritance is declared. I now call the two functions Func1 and Func2, the first behaving normally and the second showing the "weird" behavior during debugging (explanation below)

```
    int main() { 
        A* a = A::initialize(5);
        a->Func1(); // Behaves normally
        a->Func2(); // Weird behavior with this->data if you debug within Func2
    }
```

The weird behavior shows itself when stopping in Debug during the function and analyzing the calling object:

[image: Weird behavior]

There are two different values shown for the set data field, a nonsense one just under "this", and the correct one under the [A]-aspect of "this". This behavior does not occur when Func1() is called. There is obviously something going on here with the inheritence order between B1 and B2, but I honestly have no clue. Hopefully someone here can explain this :)

Comment: It's probably just a debugger bug. Does it work if you access the variable in the code?

Comment: Maybe I'm blind, but where is Instance declared. Maybe this is a pointer to a local variable and therefore invalid ?
Have you chacked running your program with "valgrind" to see if all memory access's are valid ?

Comment: That's the weird thing because it's not consistent. In this minimal example, you are right that if I do e.g. 
```
    double x = data;
```
then x is set correctly. But I've had many occasions in the original code when accessing the variables has led to the wrong behavior by obviously taking from the "wrong" this->data attribute.

Comment: Without a [mre], it is unlikely that anyone will be able to tell you anything.

Comment: You're right about the missing Instance variable. I forgot to include that in the code. Now it's in there

Comment: Looks fine in my debugger.  I suspect the problem is in your debugger, and that the problem is *probably* benign.  Unless you use the debugger interface to hot change the mystery member variable.

Comment: Temporarilly adding `printf("A is at %p\n", a);` to various locations in your code would help confirm (or deny) that there are really multiple locations for `a` or not (without relying on the debugger's code-analysis to be correct)